# how to display different price for same product in opencart?

Tags: opencart, frontend, price

Want to display different prices for a same product. Multiple sellers will be selling the same product with their respective prices is what I want to display if someone views a product....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, It's not a coding case.

1 - go to `Admin/Sales/Customers/Customers Group`, and create as many groups as you want.

2 - go to `Admin/Catalog/Products` and edit an exiting product or create a new product. in `Special` tab you can assign different prices for each group created on step 1.

Comment: I believe the products' prices vary by *seller*, not by *customer*.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have set this up is by adding fields for them in the SQL products table such as `price_a`, `price_b`, `price_c` and then adding another field to the customers table called price_category with the relevant prefix (A,B,C). Then I wrote a function under `getProduct (catalog/model/catalog/product.php)` to cater for this.

The reason I took this route is because my files are uploaded automatically to the table and links to another program which generates invoices and sends the result back to the website automatically.

My Function is as follows:

```
if ($query->rows) {
    foreach ($query1->rows as $row) {
        $price_category = strtolower($row['price_category']);
        $debtor_class = $row['debtor_class'];
        $price_percentage = $row['price_percentage'];
    }
} else {
    $price = ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']);
    $special = $query->row['special'];
}

$product_special_query = $this->db->query("SELECT price, to_qty, bonus_qty FROM product_special WHERE debtor_class = '".$debtor_class."' AND product_id = '".(int)$product_id."' AND customer_group_id = '".(int)$customer_group_id. "'");
```

Comment: What function did you write under getProduct? Will you please guide me in that...

Comment: See my function above

Comment: GETTING:-Undefined index: price_category in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 14Notice: Undefined index: debtor_class in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 15Notice: Undefined index: price_percentage in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 16Notice: Undefined variable: customer_group_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 23Notice: Error: Table 'octheme.product_special' doesn't exist
Error No: 1146

Comment: That is not a copy and paste solution. It needs to be tailored to how you would like to display the product prices and how your price setup should work

Comment: I am not that good at php sir! Will you please elaborate? Or guide me personally by mail or skype my id is pratik.sharma1619@gmail.com and pratik.sharma60 respectively please do the needful sir, I am in a deep need of it.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to make them separate products, however you might want to display a product on a single page with a list of sellers to choose from, in which case...

The different sellers are product options!